# Denoising makes fabric texture smooth

Tags: rendering, shaders, denoise

I am tying to render out a gift box with a canvas/fabric texture. Renders with Denoise turned off appear fine, albeit with plenty of noise... whilst rendering with denoise turned on will correct the noise, but also smoothen out patches of my fabric texture which I assume it is mistaking for noise (see examples).

[image: Screen-grab of a section of my box with some surface texture blurred due to denoising]

Render outputs required are 1500 x 1500 px around 5MB.
Fabric is procedural using magic texture and displacement.

[image: Fabric Shader]

New to blender but learning fast!

Many thanks!

Comment: What is your question? Denoising is well known for also removing desirable details of rendered images. If results are not good enough reduce denoise amout and increase sample count